# Assigning Relationships between various objects in a collection

Tags: data-structures, collections, relationships

Similarly to a sports team chemistry or even a better example would be fifa ultimate team chemistry where putting certain players in the team would improve the team's overall chemistry

Say there are around 20/30 possible players

How would i go about doing this with examples like this:

```
player A, player B add to the team's chemistry by 23 points i.e. ['playerA', 'playerB']
player A, player C add to the team's chemistry by 5 points
player B, player C have no chemistry
advanced: together player B, player C, player D have 7 chemistry
```

Is there a way i can easily define chemistry/relationships/links between 2 or perhaps x amount of objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple.

Start by canonicalizing each identifier, perhaps
by up-casing player names, so "a" --> "A".

For the N players involved, lexically sort them.

Define a `separator` character, perhaps `-` dash,
and enforce that it definitely cannot appear in a player ID.

Now your key is `"-".join(players)`, e.g. `"A-B-C"`.
Store `chemistry[key] = points`,
and you're done!